# Spring: requests do not reach controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing my first application with Spring, version 3.2.

Seems I've checked everything, and many times, but I only receive 404 when trying to get localhost:8080/MakeAwayTickets/ or localhost:8080/MakeAwayTickets/index. The controller isn't even being loaded, as I don't see any output from its constructor.

Files under css and js directories, like localhost:8080/MakeAwayTickets/css/dashboard.css, however, are being loaded.

Logs contain this:

```
2014-05-06T15:56:33.031+0400|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-05-06T15:56:33.446+0400|INFO: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2014-05-06T15:56:33.783+0400|SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
2014-05-06T15:56:33.783+0400|SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2014-05-06T15:56:34.013+0400|INFO: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
2014-05-06T15:56:35.017+0400|INFO: Loading application [MakeAwayTickets] at [/MakeAwayTickets]
2014-05-06T15:56:35.081+0400|INFO: MakeAwayTickets was successfully deployed in 6,888 milliseconds.
```

I have the following in configs:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>MakeAwayTickets</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.badcoding.spring.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

And here is the controller class:

```
package org.badcoding.spring.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.badcoding.dao.interfaces.TicketsDAO;
import org.badcoding.spring.form.IndexSearch;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    public IndexController() {
        System.out.println("here");
    }

    // @Autowired
    // private TicketsDAO ticketsDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index_search", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="myHeader=myValue")
    public String list_flights(@PathVariable String city_out, @PathVariable String city_in, @PathVariable String company, @PathVariable String date0, @PathVariable String date1, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("integer", 666); 

        return "index_search";
    }
}
```

I really need help with this.

Update:
After adding

```
<beans:bean class="org.badcoding.spring.controller.IndexController"/>
```

to servlet config I receive ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: What happens if you add `@ResponseBody` after `@RequestMapping("/index")`. Does it work?

Comment: Does index.jsp exist under `/WEB-INF/pages/`?

Comment: @geoand no, no changes.

Comment: And yes, the file is there, I have checked that one more time :)

Comment: I can't see anything obvious going wrong. Do you have your code on GitHub or something?

Comment: One more suggestion, what happens if you add `@RequestMapping("/")` under `@Controller`? Shouldn't make it work, but just in case

Comment: @geoand repo: https://bitbucket.org/innot/make-away-tickets, and no, that mapping doesn't really change anything

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out and see if I can get anywhere with it

Comment: If you're just starting out with Spring, I highly recommend (1) using the current version (4.0), (2) using Java-based configuration instead of XML, and (3) using Spring Boot to handle all of the standard configuration and wiring while you learn how to use controllers and other application-specific tools.

Comment: @chrylis I would, of course, use the latest version, but there were no jars on their site, and I aslo couldn't build sources from github. So, I'm using the version from my distro's repositories. Java-based configuration seemed harder to me, so I've started with xml, as there were many examples. But I will try them, as I fix the problems I'm having now or understand that I cant' do that. I will also check out Boot. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There are some getting-started guides at http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/. Note that if you're starting to use major Java components like Spring, you need to be using a build tool that manages dependencies for you, such as Maven or Gradle. Either of them knows how to resolve, download, and attach any of the release versions of Spring that have been published.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to remove below code from your configuration file

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

2.And check this `<annotation-driven />`  as there in your configration file  coming from right xsd like this  `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

3.Try to add this code in controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: 1. Done. 2. I changed xmlns= for xmlns:mvc= and added mvc: prefix in three tags there. Is that wat you meant? 3. Also done, as an additional method and as a replacement for existing index(). I see no changes, though. And, by the way, if requests were reaching the controller but it couldn't find mapping for them, wouldn't I see some notification in log?

Comment: It seems that it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this question.

Although I am configuring programmatically, the issue the controller was not being found was because I had @ComponentScan("com.ables.books.model").

Of course the controller aren't in that package so they will never be found.

I had it changed to @ComponentScan("com.ables.books") so the my classes carrying @Controller can be found wherever they are. The Equivalent of @ComponentScan in xml is context:annotation-config  so just check what you are passing to it.